# imported excel in datagridview does not show border

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am importing some excel sheets to datagridview on different forms.eg:from form 1. I am calling datagridview on form5 to import excel sheet data to it, so my issue is it opens up at form5 perfectly but when it comes back to main menu(form1) from form 5 (it closes form5 and opens form1) and then I call another datagridview in form 6 from form 1 itself, this time the cell borders especially at the lower part of datagridview doesn't show and the data seems to be not rendered properly, these are not that heavy excel files but less than even 25 rows.

excel import code:

```
Dim oform13 As Form13 = New Form13()
    oform13.Show()
    Try

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim path As String = "C:\New folder\New Building Project\Daily Checklist\abcd.xlsx"

        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)

        dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
        oform13.DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To oform13.DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            oform13.DataGridView1.Columns(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        Next i
        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
    Me.Close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t38rR.jpg)

initialize component code below:

_
    Partial Class Form13
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

```
'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Dim DataGridViewCellStyle1 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle()
    Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(Form13))
    Me.Button2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.ExportButton = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Button4 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Button6 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.DataGridView1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
    Me.GroupBox2 = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
    CType(Me.DataGridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.GroupBox2.SuspendLayout()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'Button2
    '
    Me.Button2.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Button2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(32, 34)
    Me.Button2.Name = "Button2"
    Me.Button2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(301, 49)
    Me.Button2.TabIndex = 17
    Me.Button2.Text = "Export && Email This Sheet"
    Me.Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'ExportButton
    '
    Me.ExportButton.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.ExportButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(427, 34)
    Me.ExportButton.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 5, 4, 5)
    Me.ExportButton.Name = "ExportButton"
    Me.ExportButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(221, 47)
    Me.ExportButton.TabIndex = 20
    Me.ExportButton.Text = "Only Export Sheet"
    Me.ExportButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Button4
    '
    Me.Button4.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Button4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(725, 34)
    Me.Button4.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 5, 4, 5)
    Me.Button4.Name = "Button4"
    Me.Button4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(306, 47)
    Me.Button4.TabIndex = 29
    Me.Button4.Text = "Error Notify Export && Email"
    Me.Button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Button1
    '
    Me.Button1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(1084, 34)
    Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(223, 47)
    Me.Button1.TabIndex = 30
    Me.Button1.Text = "Back to Ground Floor"
    Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Button6
    '
    Me.Button6.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Button6.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(1514, 34)
    Me.Button6.Name = "Button6"
    Me.Button6.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(156, 47)
    Me.Button6.TabIndex = 31
    Me.Button6.Text = "Main Menu"
    Me.Button6.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'DataGridView1
    '
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    Me.DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    Me.DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
    Me.DataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window
    Me.DataGridView1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Me.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 50
    DataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
    DataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window
    DataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    DataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    DataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight
    DataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText
    DataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.[True]
    Me.DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle = DataGridViewCellStyle1
    Me.DataGridView1.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke
    Me.DataGridView1.GridColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText
    Me.DataGridView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(16, 30)
    Me.DataGridView1.Name = "DataGridView1"
    Me.DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 50
    Me.DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 28
    Me.DataGridView1.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect
    Me.DataGridView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1819, 853)
    Me.DataGridView1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'GroupBox2
    '
    Me.GroupBox2.Anchor = CType(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    Me.GroupBox2.AutoSize = True
    Me.GroupBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
    Me.GroupBox2.Controls.Add(Me.DataGridView1)
    Me.GroupBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(25, 121)
    Me.GroupBox2.Name = "GroupBox2"
    Me.GroupBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1858, 912)
    Me.GroupBox2.TabIndex = 33
    Me.GroupBox2.TabStop = False
    Me.GroupBox2.Text = "CER Checklist"
    '
    'Form13
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(12.0!, 25.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.AutoScroll = True
    Me.AutoSize = True
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1908, 1034)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.GroupBox2)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button6)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button4)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.ExportButton)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button2)
    Me.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
    Me.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4)
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
    Me.Name = "Form13"
    Me.Text = "CER"
    CType(Me.DataGridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.GroupBox2.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub
Friend WithEvents Button2 As Button
Friend WithEvents ExportButton As Button
Friend WithEvents Button4 As Button
Friend WithEvents Button1 As Button
Friend WithEvents Button6 As Button
Friend WithEvents DataGridView1 As DataGridView
Friend WithEvents GroupBox2 As GroupBox
```

End Class

Comment: Unfortunately, the posted code appears to work as expected. (Minus the strange `Close()` at the end). Is it possible to show a picture of what you describe (“not rendered properly”) along with the code that displays the form with the problem grid?

Comment: hi JohnG, added the screenshot

Comment: As I stated in my comment, _“show a picture of what you describe **along with the code that displays the form**”_ … where is the Form13 designer code (InitializeComponent)? The picture looks like something is laying on top of the grid, however this is speculation without seeing how the designer is creating these items. You should take a look at how to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i have added the initialize component code for form13, please have a look

Comment: Unfortunately, that code does not reproduce the problem. It worked as expected. In addition, the posted code does not look like the posted picture. The posted picture and posted code are not the same. There must be something else going on in the posted picture.

Comment: Hi johnG, regardless of the form number, the issue happens to me, as I said, on the second form loaded,first form is loaded fine with the dgview,but the second form(whichever form number) which has a dgview in it shows the problem.so in this case for eg:form13 will load fine and then i go back to form5, the problem occurs or vice versa, if i load form5 with dgview initially its ok and then load form13,the issue happens.hope i am able to explain.thanks..i tried putting refresh button, it somewhat clears the issue but not fully,and i am not happy with that solution,something to do with gfx card?

Comment: Regardless of the form number, I cannot reproduce what you describe from the given code. I will assume I am missing something and move on. Good Luck!